# Missing paramenter when I use map (Scala)

Tags: scala, dictionary, httprequest

I'm having an irritating error which I can't find any explanation for. 
I have this code here below:

```
Async{
  WS.url(url).get().map{ response =>  //response here is giving me the error.
    Ok("Response: " + (response.json \ "media_count").as[String])
  }
}
```

And this gives me an error saying:

```
missing parameter type
```

on the response.

Where should I define this parameter type? Or what is this error saying more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code right now, finally got it to work. I think I was thinking to complex and hard. Sometimes it is'nt that complicated. Now I can face some new obstacles and find new fun solutions :)

```
Async{
  try{
    WS.url(requestUrl).get().map{ response =>
      val param = (response.json.\("data").\("media_count"))
      Ok(param.toString())
    }
  } catch {
    case _:Throwable => {
      Promise.pure(Ok("there was an error"))
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Scala allows you to use methods as operators. So instead of `(response.json.\("data").\("media_count"))` you could say `(response.json \ "data" \ "media_count")`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `play.libs.WS` which is meant for the Java API.

The `WS.url(...).get()` for this WS class returns a `Promise` object of this type: [Promise](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html). The `map` function for this class takes a [`Function`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/libs/F.Function.html) instance, which is not the same as `Function1` from Scala. This is causing your compiler error.

If you're working in Scala you should use `play.api.libs.ws.WS` which is meant to work with the Scala library. Replace `import play.libs.WS` with `import play.api.libs.ws.WS` in your program and the error should go away.

Comment: Great thanks, that particular error disappeared but now another appeared. In my terminal window I get an error saying `[error] play - Waiting for a promise, but got an error: String expected` and then nothing happens. I get redirected to my "Ok()" but it is empty. It should atleast show something like "Response: null" I assume.

Comment: Maybe there is no "media_count" in the json, or it's not a string. From the name of the property it sounds numeric. Anyway, you won't get null. If the future fails, an exception should appear in logs and if you're in dev mode than the redish screen with the error should appear in the browser. Try changing the `as[String]` bit into `(response.json \ "media_count").asOpt[String]`. `asOpt` will return an `Option[String]`. If it returns `None` then `media_count` isn't what you thought it is. Or better yet, return a `Ok(Json.prettyPrint(response.json))` to see exactly what you get.

Comment: I'm not able to try this just now but thanks! I'll look into this when I'm able to. One thing I'm thinking about is that shouldnt my code atleast show my string "Response: " ? Havent had the time to look so much but I assume thats because I'm getting an error before it can write out any "Response: ".

Comment: Is this Json.prettyPrint() some plugin or?

Comment: @RobertAxelsson No, it's part of the standard API: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$. Regarding your previous question, if the future fails it won't provide some default value like "" or `null`. It will fail the entire request, probably returning a 500 error code.

Comment: I think you are correct about that "media_count" not is a string. Because when I write out only the `response.json` I get the json response I want, including "media_count" but as you said it might not be of the type string. Regarding the `prettyPrint()` method, I import play.api.libs.json.Json but it still tells me that `prettyPrint`is not a member of the api.

Comment: thanks! Finally I got it to work, gonna put my solution in another post.